# async / await: asynchronous array transformation using Array.prototype.map (works) vs Array.prototype.filter (not working)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I'm almost positive there has to be an explanation for this, but I just spent over an hour trying to figure out why my async code was appearing to resolve early when trying to transform an array using `ary.filter()`, but when using `ary.map()` async resolves when I'd expect it to. Anyone who can help shed some light on this topic would be greatly appreciated!

I'm also using node 8.2.1 just for clarity.

So to provide some code and output to describe the issue, here is an example of using `ary.map` that **works** and provides the following output in the console.

```
(async () => {
  const timeStart = Date.now()
  const ary = new Array(20).fill(0).map((v, i) => i+1)

  const newAry = await Promise.all(
    ary.map(async val => {
      return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(val*2), 1000)
      })
    })
  )
  console.log('original ary', ary)
  console.log('newAry is', newAry)
  const timeEnd = Date.now()
  console.log(timeEnd - timeStart, 'milliseconds between start and end')
})()
```

The output to the console is as follows:

```
original ary [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 ]
newAry is [ 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40 ]
1022 milliseconds between start and end
```

So as you'd expect, there is ~1 seconds between when the original array is transformed, and the output is as expected.

The following code is very similar, but uses `ary.filter()` and does **not** return as expected.

```
(async () => {
  const timeStart = Date.now()
  const ary = new Array(20).fill(0).map((v, i) => i+1)

  const newAry = await Promise.all(
    ary.filter(async val => {
      return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(Math.random() < 0.5), 1000)
      })
    })
  )
  console.log('original ary', ary)
  console.log('newAry is', newAry)
  const timeEnd = Date.now()
  console.log(timeEnd - timeStart, 'milliseconds between start and end')
})()
```

The output is as follows:

```
original ary [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 ]
newAry is [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 ]
18 milliseconds between start and end
```

Why does `ary.filter()` not behave the same as `ary.map()` in terms of transforming the array and resolving at the appropriate time when using async/await?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `Promise.all()` only makes sense on an array of promises.

`.map()` returns the result of its callback, which, if the callback is async, is a promise.  Therefore, that works fine.

`.filter()` treats the result of its callback as a boolean (which it isn't), then returns the items in the original array.

Comment: Ahhh thanks I think I get it, but just to confirm, since in my example I'm returning a promise to `.filter()`, this is always truthy and I will get all elements of my original array? I'm assuming there's not a workaround for this other than some utility that I'm sure exists in bluebird (trying to use native promises if possible) or by writing a few extra lines of code to use .map to return true/false somehow and then filter on that array?

Comment: @LanceWhatley: Correct.

Comment: Thanks again, can't accept your answer yet since it hasn't been enough time, but will accept shortly.